# Why does longtable not process \medskip inside a row, but tabular does?

Tags: tables, longtable

How can one make `longtable` not ignore `\midskip` at start of a table row?

In the following MWE, I am trying to add little space in a row. It works OK with `tabular`, but not in `longtable`.

Here is a `tabular` MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
[c]{|l|l|m{3in}|}\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunction\\\hline
$y\left(  0\right)  =0$ & $y\left(  L\right)  =0$ &
\medskip
\begin{tabular}
[c]{|l|l||l|}\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda>0$ & $\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots$ &
$\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  $\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which gives after compiling with `lualatex`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I do the same exact thing, but use `longtable`. No other changes. The space above the inner table now is gone (but the one below it remains there):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}
[c]{|l|l|m{3in}|}\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunction\\\hline
$y\left(  0\right)  =0$ & $y\left(  L\right)  =0$ &
\medskip
\begin{tabular}
[c]{|l|l||l|}\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda>0$ & $\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots$ &
$\sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)  $\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I sort of remember seeing something like this. Something about `longtable` handles spaces little differently, but I can't recall what it is.

How can make `longtable` generate the same output as `tabular`? My table is long, and that is why I need to use `longtable`.

#### Screen log

```
lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
(using write cache: /home/me/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)(using
 read cache: /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic /home/me/.t
exlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.129 seconds
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: /home/m
e/.texlive2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc))
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty) (./foo.aux)
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) detected at line 23
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./foo.aux))
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 450 words of node memory still in use:
   5 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 1 kern, 5 attribute, 53 glue_spec, 5 attri
bute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:159,3:30,4:2,5:37,6:242,7:363,8:89,9:168,11:14
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.p
fb></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pf
b></usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></
usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr
/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page, 53623 bytes).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

Comment: Not an answer to the "why" question, but change your `[c]` parameter to `[t]` in the `longtable` version and it will do what you want.

Comment: @AlanMunn - This solution does leave some space above the framed `tabular` in the third column. However, the framed tabular is not guaranteed to be aligned with the material in the first two rows.

Comment: @Mico Ah, right. I didn't think about that issue.

Comment: this is actually rather a good question, I don't see the answer immediately, but I'm travelling today so may not get back to it, a challenge for  egreg to investigate before I get home:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

longtable inserts a strut at the begin of p-cell. This means that TeX is no longer in vertical mode and so the `\medskip` has a different effect. If one remove this strut the output is identical (but it could have side effects ...):

### Edit

The Issue has been reported (https://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html.new?pr=tools/3785). So the solution is known, the main question is how to add to longtable without breaking existing documents ...

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\LTleft=\parindent

\begin{tabular}{p{3in}}\hline
\relax\ifvmode yes \else no \fi %\medskip
xxxx
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{p{3in}}\hline
\relax\ifvmode yes \else no \fi %\medskip
xxxx
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{longtable}



\begin{tabular}{p{3in}}\hline
\medskip
xxxx
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\makeatletter
\def\LT@startpbox#1{%
  \bgroup
    \let\@footnotetext\LT@p@ftntext
    \setlength\hsize{#1}%
    \@arrayparboxrestore
    %\vrule \@height \ht\@arstrutbox \@width 1pt 
    }
\makeatother
\begin{longtable}{p{3in}}\hline
\medskip
xxxx
\medskip
\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As Ulrike pointed out, the difference is due to a difference in strut handling.

You are using `array` package

In general `longtable` follows `array` usage, it documents

```
% The rest of this macro is mainly based on \package{array} package, but
% should work for the standard \env{tabular} too.
```

However there was a more recent change to `array` that is not reflected in `longtable`

```
% \changes{v2.1c}{1992/12/14}{Use `everypar to insert strut}
%    \begin{macrocode}
   \everypar{%
      \vrule \@height \ht\@arstrutbox \@width \z@
      \everypar{}}%
   }
%    \end{macrocode}
```

However `longtable` uses the pre 1992 version

```
    \vrule \@height \ht\@arstrutbox \@width \z@}
```

You would think the authors of the `array` and `longtable` packages might have communicated with each other during the last 25 years but apparently not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\vadjust pre`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|m{3in}|}\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunction\\\hline
$y(0) = 0$ & $y(L) = 0$ &
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|}\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda>0$ & $(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\dotsc$ &
$\sin(\frac{n\pi}{L}x)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}\medskip
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|m{3in}|}\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunction\\\hline
$y(0) = 0$ & $y(L) = 0$ &
\vadjust pre{\vspace{\medskipamount}}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|}\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\\hline
$\lambda>0$ & $(\frac{n\pi}{L})^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\dotsc$ &
$\sin(\frac{n\pi}{L}x)$\\\hline
\end{tabular}\vspace{\medskipamount}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Please, note also the proper input (no `\left` and `\right`; `\dotsc` instead of `\cdots`). The `[c]` option is different for `longtable` and `tabular` (but is the default for both).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but it's as simple to use the `\Gape` command, from `makecell`. For the nested tabular, it looks nicer to use  `hhline.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}
[c]{|l|l|m{3in}|}
\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunction\\\hline
$y\left( 0\right) =0$ & $y\left( L\right) =0$ &
\medskip
\Gape[6pt][0pt]{\setcellgapes{2pt}\makegapedcells\begin{tabular}
[c]{|l|l||l|}\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\ \hhline{|-|-||-|}
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\ \hhline{|-|-||-|}
$\lambda>0$ & $\Bigl( \mfrac{n\pi}{L}\Bigr)^{\!2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots$ &
$\sin\Bigl( \mfrac{n\pi}{L}x\Bigr) $\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following, admittedly somewhat hackish, solution works in a `longtable` env: Insert both a `\vskip*{-\medskipamount}` *and* a blank line immediately before the framed tabular, and insert a blank line *after* the framed tabular.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,longtable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}

% first, a centered "tabular" env.
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|l|l|m{3in}@{}|}\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions\\\hline
$y(0) =0$ & $y(L) =0$ & 
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|}
\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\ \hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\ \hline
$\lambda>0$ & $\bigl( \frac{n\pi}{L}\bigr)^{2\mathstrut} \qquad n=1,2,3,\dots$ &
$\sin\bigl( \frac{n\pi}{L\mathstrut}x \bigr)  $\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\medskip
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


% second, a longtable env.
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|m{3in}@{}|}
\hline
Left & right & eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endlastfoot

$y(0) =0$ & $y(L) =0$ & 
\vspace*{-\medskipamount}
% leave a blank line

\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|}
\hline
$\lambda<0$ & None & None\\ \hline
$\lambda=0$ & None & None\\ \hline
$\lambda>0$ & $\bigl( \frac{n\pi}{L}\bigr)^{2\mathstrut} \qquad n=1,2,3,\dots$ &
$\sin\bigl( \frac{n\pi}{L\mathstrut}x \bigr)  $\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
% leave a blank line

\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```