# Different behaviour of p-columns in longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

Sometimes a macro might start with `\par`. Such a macro poses usually no problem in a `p` column. However, when an assignment precedes it, something seems to go wrong when using `{longtable}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lp{3cm}}
\hline
foo & \def\foo{}\par hi \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}[l]{lp{3cm}}% "l" just for screenshot
\hline
foo & \def\foo{}\par hi \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is `longtable` here doing differently from a normal `tabular`?

Comment: that's interesting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413522/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ah thanks it was obviously a strut difference but was too tired last night to work out where:-) Since Frank and I obviously can't be blamed, we'll have to blame you, I guess this can be closed as dup, but perhaps I should update longtable ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I could open a latex2e issue and make a PR ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=64247330#64247330

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks! Do you want to write an answer or close as dupe?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clearly changing `longtable` after so many years might break a lot of documents... maybe a package option `fixthebugwhichisntmyfault`? `:-)`

Comment: @campa joking aside I need to decide whether this is fixable (by default) or not, so I won't rush out an update

Comment: probably close as dup here as it's already at the other one and Ulrike opened an issue at github